# Question on ActiveX Script Task in Sql Server 2000 dts package

Tags: sql-server-2000, activex, dts

What does this line of code do

```
Set Pkg = DTSGlobalVariables.Parent
```

In the following ActiveX Script Task:

```
Function Main()
    myfilename=inputbox( "Please enter the filename (ex. 2010Nov):")    
    Set Pkg = DTSGlobalVariables.Parent
     DTSGlobalVariables("filename").Value=myfilename
    Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success
End Function
```

in a Sql Server dts package?

Answer (score 0):

DTSGlobalVariables.Parent - the package object itself.
The script assigns it to your variable Pkg, but doesn't use it.